# R plotly: Click in a graph and creates a new one or filters other

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

It is possible to have a time series graph in plotly that when you click a data point in it, it will generate another graph (next to it)?

For example, a graph with the time series of the price of a stock. And when you click the price on a particular date (lets say 10-jun-2017) a new graph appears that has the daily return histogram of that stock until 10-jun-2017.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen https://plot.ly/r/shiny-coupled-events/? Does that help?

Comment: @Ameya hi. not using shiny for this.